# Schedule tasks with Spring boot and db-scheduler which run after server restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler

With Spring boot and kagkarlsson db-scheduler configured, through a rest request I create a dynamic OneTimeTask and it gets scheduled and works. However, if the task is scheduled in future say 70s, and I restart server, then I see following message in logs and the task is not run:

```
2023-01-18 18:29:27.527  WARN 1 --- [pool-4-thread-1] c.g.k.scheduler.jdbc.JdbcTaskRepository  : Failed to find implementation for task with name 'ad-hoc-task-test'. Execution will be excluded from due. Either delete the execution from the database, or add an implementation for it. The scheduler may be configured to automatically delete unresolved tasks after a certain period of time.
```

RestController:

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/dbsched", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void dbScheduleATask(@RequestBody TaskDefinition taskDefinition) {
        OneTimeTask<TaskDefinition> adhocTask = Tasks.oneTime("ad-hoc-task-test", TaskDefinition.class)
                .execute((inst, ctx) -> {
                    System.out.println("Executed! Custom data, Id: " + inst.getData());
                });

        final Scheduler scheduler = Scheduler
                .create(dataSource, adhocTask)
                .registerShutdownHook()
                .build();

        scheduler.start();

        TaskDefinition td = new TaskDefinition();
        td.setData("test");

        scheduler.schedule(adhocTask.instance("1045", td),
                Instant.now().plusSeconds(70));

        System.out.println("Run job...");
    }
```

Please advise how I can get the task to run automatically after server restart.

Thanks.

Comment: it looks like scheduler is not getting saved in db, that's why after restart it unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the SchedulerClient bean , that have a schedule method too..
but also show how you defined your table in db

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the scheduler initializes, the scheduler doesn't have the adHocTask registered, like you did here:

```
        final Scheduler scheduler = Scheduler
            .create(dataSource, adhocTask) <------------
            .registerShutdownHook()
            .build();
```

Therefore, when the scheduler initializes with the server and finds the task in its table, it doesn't know what to do with a task of this type.

The declaration of `adHocTask` should be added as part of the initialization of the server. For example, if you declare your scheduler in the initalization of the server you should register the adHocTask into it like you are doing in this controller.

If you are using springboot, make adHocTask a bean inside a configuration class and db-scheduler will auto-detect it, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigClass {
        
  @Bean
  private OneTimeTask<TaskDefinition> adHocTask() {
    OneTimeTask<TaskDefinition> adhocTask = Tasks.oneTime("ad-hoc-task-test", TaskDefinition.class)
            .execute((inst, ctx) -> {
              System.out.println("Executed! Custom data, Id: " + inst.getData());
            });
  }
        
}
```